# What were untreated gangrene survival rates before 1860?

Tags: medicine

During the Civil War, Middleton Goldsmith revolutionized the treatment of gangrene, bringing mortality rates (presumably of wounded soldiers) from 45% to 3%, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gangrene#History).

Do we have any data to suggest what mortality rates would have been at the time **without** treatment by doctors? I'm most interested in whether or not the number is above or below 45%--the root question is whether or not surgical treatment of gangrene helped or harmed, but I would much rather try to answer that with statistics than observations about medical practice. (For example, I know that al-Kharzawi recommended amputation, and thus it was standard practice in the West, but that doesn't tell me that it actually helped.)

Comment: Before that time medical "statistics" were not commonly collected. Also, gangrene was much less well understood.

Comment: Jean Larrey's *flying ambulances*, modeled on French horse artillery, was doing that for Napoleon decades earlier.